# double whammy usage for two good things?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

The phrase "double whammy" is used in a situation where two bad things happen but can it be used in a situation where two good things happen?

I didn't know "double whammy" is used in a situation with two bad things! All I believed was whammy was something good.

Can anyone suggest another phrase for a situation where two good things happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A whammy is never good.

> Origin 1940s: from the noun wham + -y1; associated from the 1950s with the cartoon strip Li'l Abner, in which the hillbilly Evil-Eye Fleegle could ‘shoot a whammy’ (to put a curse on somebody) by pointing a finger with one eye open, and a ‘double whammy’ with both eyes open.

The antonym to a curse would be a blessing.

So you could use *double blessing*

Answer (score 3):

In addition to mplungjan's double blessing (e.g., The parents were doubly blessed in having twins), one could also say that sbdy had 'twice the luck' or was 'doubly favoured.'

But a more exact opposite to 'whammy' would be 'stroke of luck' or 'lucky break' or maybe even 'fluke' in the right context.  So the opposite of 'double whammy' would be something like 'two strokes of luck' or 'a pair of lucky breaks.'

Comment: If a whammy is a curse, how can stroke of luck be antonym?

Comment: A double blessing is quite common but two strokes of luck? Surely a stroke by its very meaning implies it is a one off occasion, if two positive events happened simultaneously it would no longer be likened to a stroke. (I'm just thinking aloud).

Comment: @mplungjan a whammy is also used to describe a negative event: "A serious or devastating setback" not only a curse, or giving someone the evil eye.

Comment: 'Curse' is in the etymology, but that's not how I suspect most people use it nowadays (e.g., http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20whammy).  Now it's just "two bad things happening (simultaneously)", as per OP.

Comment: @Mari-Lou "two strokes of luck" gives 67,500 results on Google, might be worth looking at.

Comment: Would "two lucky breaks" be or sound more natural? Checked on Google, and you're right, two strokes of luck is fairly common. I even skimmed through a few articles, just to be double sure. Thank you!

Comment: "to get a lucky break" seems to be a common idiom, and so I guess by extensions, people use "X gets/got two lucky breaks"

Comment: stroke of luck seems more appropriate with double whammy, bcoz the other day i congratulated someone for being lucky twice and said "dats a double whammy"

Answer (score 0):

I think 'double pleasure' is the real deal. That's because whammy represents a negative event-an event against an individuals survival. A good event is something that adds value to an individuals survival. Such events cause pleasure. getting two pleasures at the same time is a 'double pleasure'

Comment: I would not use "pleasure" for something that can happen by itself or happened to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Double whammy by itself = understood to be bad.  (You went to take your driving test, and not only didn't pass, but got a flat tire in the process.  Not just two bad things, but two bad things that *compound*.)

*Double whammy of good fortune*, how about.  "Double dose of good luck?"  Just doesn't have the same impact.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an equivalent expression in the opposite, depending on the usage, could be *two birds with one stone*.

*Double whammy* = double trouble.

*Two bird with one stone* = double progress.